# Parse value of the dot separated string from JSON in ruby

Tags: json, ruby, parsing

How to grab the value of input string `this.is.string` from json in ruby.

JSON file `test.json` looks like this:

```json
{
  "this": {
    "is": {
      "string": "value"
    }
  }
}
```

```rb
# Opening the json file to read the data
json_file = File.open("test.json")

# Reading the data from the json file
data_from_file = JSON.load(json_file)

get_value = data_from_file["this"]["is"]["string"]
```

works, but how to determine how many elements I need to use in `data_from_file["this"]["is"]["string"]` ?

What if the input string is `this.is.yet.another.string`? Is there any determinisitc way how to achieve this, please?

**UPDATE**

It seems that this works fine:

```rb
def get_value(data, query)
  query.split('.').inject(data) do |v, k|
    k = k.to_i if v.is_a? Array
    v.fetch(k)
  end
end

get_value(data_from_file, 'this.is.string')
=> "value"
```

Comment: Just be careful with `k.to_i` because `"RaHan".to_i #=> 0`

Comment: thanks @engineersmnky, that's just in case it's an array (which is not the case in here), so I can actually remove that part, or what would you suggest to handle the "array" situation?

Comment: How to handle would be up to you. If Arrays are not a concern then `data.dig(*query.split('.'))` will work just fine. For conversion you could use `Integer(k, exception:false)` as needed.